# Android Studio. How to change template for generating "toString()" method?

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio 2.3.

Following is the default template for **toString()** method

[image]

How can I change this template?

Comment: you cannot change the default tostring template instead create your own template and use that, click + on and add your template

Answer (score 1):

You can not change the default template, but you can add your custom template and use that instead of default.

Follow these steps to add a new template.

1. Press (Alt+Insert) or **Go to Code -> Generate** and select toString() from the contextual menu: This will open following window

   [image]
2. In the opened dialog box, click on the Settings button on top right corner.
   a new dialog box will open with two tabs(Settings and Templates).
3. Select the Templates tab and it will show following dialog.

   [image: Templates Tab]
4. Use the + sign on top left corner to define your own template